How to implement unit tests for WinUI3 (C++) application
At the moment, I have created a test project using a project template from Visual Studio Unit Test App (Winui 3) and my code looks like this
namespace TestMyWinrtApp
{
    TEST_CLASS(CppUnitTests)
    {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(CppTestOne)
        {
            try {
                auto bp = winrt::make< winrt::MyUI::implementation::BlankPage>();
                Button btn = bp.FindName(L"myButton").as<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Button>();
                winrt::hstring btnTag = btn.Tag().as<winrt::hstring>();
                Assert::IsTrue(btnTag == L"MyTag");
            } catch (const winrt::hresult_error& ex) {
                MessageBox(
                    NULL,                  
                    ex.message().c_str(), 
                    L"Error", 
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION
                );
            }
        }
    };
}

However, after starting the tests, I get the exception: "The Application Called An Interface that was Marshalled for a Different Thread". As far as I know, this exception thrown is due to the fact that I try to create an winrt::make< winrt::MyUI::implementation::BlankPage>() UI element outside the UI thread. I found a solution for C# which is to add an [UITestMethod] attribute for the test method. But how i can do unit tests like this in C++ test project?

Should the test be written in [tag:c++-cli]?

@πάνταῥεῖ no, i want to use standard c++17

Well, then the c# code might be hard to adapt for this.

@πάνταῥεῖ in general, i am interested in any c++ solution

You're probably better off looking up c++-cli, since that might (should) support that [UITestMethod] as well and easy as with c#.

@πάνταῥεῖ I have no idea how can i create 100% compatible (with my WinUI3 C++ application) C++/CLI application

Either write your unit tests in C# for your C++ production code, or use a C++ unit test framework like Google Test, Boost Test, Catch2, or (my favorite) doctest.  Also, unit test frameworks are not terribly hard to roll your own from scratch, with just enough implementation to satisfy your project's needs.

If the issue is that you are using WinUI components (I see a Button in your snippet) that require a working UI thread, then the solution can be to create a regular WinUI application and execute the tests manually from the OnLaunched method. The linked example uses C# (and NUnit) but you get the idea. Console writes are redirected into a custom ConsoleRenderer control so the result is similar to a dotnet test ... output.

Furthermore, from the test methods the execution should be marshaled to the UI thread by DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue. Again, a C# example. And here is how this can be used from a test case (note the body wrapped into ExecuteTest(() => {...})).

@GyörgyKőszeg I had a similar idea before, but I want a standard solution. If there are no other proposals, then perhaps I will do this. Thank you anyway :)

What the .NET implementation does is not magic, the code is here https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/6888a7fde284c0b5d060ce932b8622a5c9550a78/src/TestFramework/TestFramework.Extensions/Attributes/WinUI_UITestMethodAttribute.cs#L58 you can do the same in c++, but it's a bit work since you don't have the Task class (and associated) facility.

@SimonMourier The problem is that in the unit test I cannot access the UI thread for add callback into the queue because this call winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView().CoreWindow().Dispatcher().TryRunAsync(priority, callback) throws exception "could not create new view because the main window has not yet been created" so approach which you suggested does not work in my case

There's no CoreApplication nor CoreWindow with WinUI3, these are for UWP only. Just look at the code, they are MicrosoftXXX namespace not WindowsXXX namespace. Of course the approach works, it's exactly the same environment, but you're just not using the same classes.

@SimonMourier you are right, i am already do this and want to give thanks to you (if you interested in details, see my answer below)

The Problem is solved. As @Simon Mourier & @György Kőszeg suggested in comments, we can We can add a task to the ui thread queue to use the ui elements there. To access the ui thread queue, I used a global variable because I did not find any other way to access the ui thread queue other than through a global variable whose value is assigned in the OnLaunched method in the App class after activating the main window. Finally, solution looks like this:
#include <winrt/base.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
using namespace winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;
extern winrt::Microsoft::UI::Dispatching::DispatcherQueue UIDispatcherQueue;

TEST(UITEST, first)
{
    std::promise<bool> p;
    std::future<bool> f = p.get_future();
    bool enqueued = UIDispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Dispatching::DispatcherQueuePriority::High, [&p]()
    {
        auto bp = winrt::make< winrt::WinUIGtest::implementation::BlankPage>();
        Button btn = bp.FindName(L"myButton").as<Button>();
        winrt::hstring btnTag = btn.Tag().as<winrt::hstring>();
        bool isEquals = (btnTag == L"MyTag");
        p.set_value(isEquals);
    });

    bool res = f.get();
    ASSERT_EQ(res, true);
}

As you can see, I was also changed test framework to google test. If you want to do so, then you need:

Install google test in your project
Run google tests manually (you can do it in the App::OnLaunched method)

Note: If you want to run tests which should enqueue callback in the UI thread, you should run tests in the separate thread, otherwise this action seems like produced deadlock.
    // allocate console to see gtest output
    if (AllocConsole()) {
        FILE* pStdout, * pStderr;
        freopen_s(&pStdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        freopen_s(&pStderr, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    }
    
    // run gtest in separate thread
    std::thread([]
    {
        int argc = 1;
        char** fakeArgv = new char* [1];
        char* path = new char[1024];
        strcpy_s(path, 1024, R"(C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\WinUIGtest\x64\Debug\WinUIGtest\WinUIGtest.exe)");
        fakeArgv[0] = path;
        ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, fakeArgv);
        //::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, fakeArgv);
    
        RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    }).detach();
    
    // disable standard tests
    //winrt::Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestPlatform::TestExecutor::WinRTCore::UnitTestClient::Run(m_args);

